# Minimizing number of Three.js Draws

Tags: performance, three.js

I'm testing the use of Three.js for my project (http://agentscript.org) and the first test seems quite slow:

> https://asx-vqnhxlahpe.now.sh/test.html?three0

(note: the site can take a while, it "sleeps" after a period of non-use)

This is apparently due to my using way too many draws, one per agent.

`renderer.info.render
Object {calls: 10002, vertices: 60090, faces: 20000, points: 0}`

I believe using a BufferGeometry would solve this, but I don't know how to use one and still be able to access each individual agent so that my step/animate function can modify (move, rotate) them.

How would I do this?

I realize I could simply go to using my own Shader, and plan to do so, but I'd prefer to have an intermediate solution or two first.

Comment: which version of three.js are you using? What type of Geometry?

Comment: Here is the source code: https://asx-vqnhxlahpe.now.sh/test/apps/three0.js

Comment: I'm using three@0.82.1. The geometry is simply two triangles per agent to make them look dart-like. I instance the agents in the scene by adding one new mesh, pointing to the single geometry and material (red).

Comment: Note: unchecked the answer because the conversation is so great and for some reason SO does not notify me. I also plan to try one of the other answers to make sure I really understand it. Thanks for your patience! And help.

Comment: @backspaces You specifically asked for an intermediate solution that used `BufferGeometry`, was performant, and did not require a custom shader. Please do not change the question after it has been answered. If you need more help, make a new post.

Comment: Agreed, I'll open a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to reduce the number of draw calls in your Agent simulation and get something working relatively easily. You can do that by representing your collection of agents as `THREE.Points`.

```
// geometry
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

// attributes
var positions = new Float32Array( numAgents * 3 ); // 3 values per vertex
var rotations = new Float32Array( numAgents * 1 ); // 1 values per vertex

for ( var i = 0; i < numAgents; i ++ ) {

    positions[ i ] = 0;
    positions[ i + 1 ] = 0;
    positions[ i + 2 ] = 0;
    rotations[ i ] = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();

}

geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'rotation', new THREE.BufferAttribute( rotations, 1 ) );

// material
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( {

    color: 0xff0000,
    size: 4,
    map: null

} );

// points
points = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
scene.add( points );
```

This will render in a single draw call and you can update the positions on the CPU and push the data to the GPU each frame. You should be able to render 100,000 agents easily.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/730ffn4x/

If you want to represent your points as an arrow with direction, you would need to provide texture with an arrow image and a custom `ShaderMaterial` to rotate each point.

`InstancedBufferGeometry` is appropriate if each agent must be represented as a `Mesh`. [Here is a fine example](http://codepen.io/usefulthink/full/YNrvpY) by @MartinSchuhfuß that is similar to what you want to do.

For intense simulations, you would use GPGPU. [See the three.js examples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=GPGPU). In GPGPU, the simulation runs entirely on the GPU, and the CPU typically does minimal work.

three.js r.84

Comment: Whoa .. great minds think alike! My team (simtable.com) asked trying points: http://backspaces.github.io/asx/test.html?threepts which gets 100K agents @ 60fps easily.

Comment: But my goal is a simpler idea: a BufferGeometry that may be space-heavy but uses just one draw. I'm not sure yet if this can be done without ShaderMaterials, I think use of standard attr names lets Three use a Three shader, but I don't know the details of the standard  BufferGeometry attrs. I suspect I'd have to use an attr array of matrices.  Conversation here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10666#issuecomment-275803140 @mrdoob points to using indexed, and as you suggested there, I'm looking at PlaneBufferGeometry today, thanks.

Comment: Oops .. when I said "my goal is a simpler idea: a BufferGeometry", I should be clear that the buffer would represent triangles, not points.

Comment: you can used InstancedBufferGeometry to hold one definition of a geometry (an arrow for example) and attributes for transformation. It's basically the same idea but instead of moving singular points around, (they have no rotation or scale) you move a matrix around. If you apply the same idea of a point cloud to a mesh, youd have to hold a definition for N shapes. Each shape would have to have it vertices transformed vs just one vertex in the point cloud. Instancing solves this. You dont touch the geometry, just update the instance attributes.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, instancing is the best way to reduce geometries and draw calls. `Three.js` supports instancing through `ANGLE_instanced_arrays` extension.

Take a look at this -

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/InstancedBufferGeometry

Also here is an example on how to do instancing in `Three.js` -

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing.html

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. Using renderer.info.render did indeed show a single draw. calls: 1, vertices: 195000, faces: 65000, points: 0. It looks like his RawShaderMaterial (to avoid Three building matrices, he uses a single uniform for matrices).

Comment: So is there a way to use instancing so that a shader is not needed? Not that I mind doing so, it's just to evaluate Three.js strategies for a model like I show: lots of independent "agents" with their own x,y and z-rotation.

Comment: Oops, forgot to finish the first comment, should read:  It looks like his RawShaderMaterial (to avoid Three building matrices, he uses a single uniform for matrices) does the individual triangle positioning/rotation .. gotta grok it tho first.

Comment: Unfortunately, all these lower-level features always require you to write your own shaders, simply because you need to add the handling of the instance-attributes. Extending existing shaders in three.js is also extremely complicated. But that shouldn't be too complicated to do for the usecase shown in your example.

Comment: Here's a preview of three.js object that hooks the instancing functionality with the regular shaders. https://github.com/pailhead/three-instanced-mesh. It might make it into three but the api needs to be reworked. The shader chunks do need to be monkey patched but you can consult this pattern, or even use this as is, but add a method to set the mat4 attribute at an instance index. (right now available only through construction)

Comment: @MartinSchuhfuß turns out that extending shaders its not too complicated, but clunky and hacky. Material uses some undocumented features that make this a breeze. Look up `Material.defines` `Material.customDepthMaterial` and `Material.customDistanceMaterial`, i modified the renderer a bunch in order to make this work before, but now it's totally possible to do it entirely from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, using BufferGeometries would help a lot in your case.

This is something I came up with: First, we will have a small helper-class that will represent an arrow:

```
// the base-shape of the arrow, two triangles
const arrowVertices = new Float32Array([
  -1,-1,0, 0,0,0, 0,2,0,
  0,2,0, 0,0,0, 1,-1, 0
]);

// some helper-variables
const v3 = new THREE.Vector3();
const m4 = new THREE.Matrix4();

class Arrow {
  constructor(buffer, offset) {
    this.numVertices = 6;
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.offset = offset;
    this.heading = 0;
    this.position = new THREE.Vector3();
  }

  update() {
    m4.makeRotationZ(this.heading)
        .setPosition(this.position);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.numVertices; i++) {
      v3.fromArray(arrowVertices, i * 3);
      v3.applyMatrix4(m4a);
      v3.toArray(this.buffer, this.offset + i * 3);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, to use it, setup the BufferGeometry and "attach" the arrows to it

```
// create the bufferGeometry (note: if you want proper shading, you will 
// also need an attribute 'normal' with face-vertex-normals)
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const positionBuffer = new Float32Array(NUM_INSTANCES * 6 * 3);

geometry.addAttribute('position', 
    new THREE.BufferAttribute(positionBuffer, 3));

const arrow = new Arrow(positionBuffer, 0);
const anotherArrow = new Arrow(positionBuffer, 6);

arrow.position.set(2, 1, 0);
arrow.heading = Math.PI/180 * 30;
arrow.update();
```

The main drawback of this technique is that you need to manually handle all the transforms of the arrow-vertices. For simple arrows with just 6 vertices this shouldn't be that much of a problem and it will likely perform way better than a mesh per arrow. However, I would recommend you have another look at instanced geometries, which could do all the stuff happening in the update-method above in the vertex-shader and thus perform even better with less overhead.

Comment: Noob question: Does THREE.BufferGeometry require use of ShaderMaterial? Or can it be used without shaders, using the standard Three rendering?

Comment: all geometries in threejs get converted to buffergeometries, so yes

Comment: Is there an example of instancing without using shaders? I find the docs pretty opaque. In one of the discussions I believe you were involved in @mrdoob replied "At the moment, there is no way to use instancing unless you know glsl." I only care because I'm working with a team that would prefer to use "vanilla Three". I'm fine with ShaderMaterials if need be.

Comment: @backspaces no, using instancing together with the materials three.js provides is as of now not possible. But, if you don't need complicated shading-stuff (like shadows, skeletal animation, complex reflection-models etc), writing such a shader is not as complicated as it might sound.

Comment: You can inject some code into the existing shaders. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshphysical_vert.glsl would be the source of the standard PBR shader's vert part. You'd need to add some logic to read an additional attribute, and do the instancing transformation. You'd best do this in object space, then apply the world transformation to the entire cluster of instanced stuff.

Comment: Martin, what does theory say about this approach you've outlined above? You're updating portions of the buffer on each tick, is it still supposed to be more efficient than draw calls, or could it actually be worse? I don't quite understand how this syncing happens with the gpu. I understand it would be happening with an instanced attribute too, except it would have less data - per instance, instead of per vertex - per instance.

Comment: So, there is some work being done on the js-side to update the attribute-buffers, but that is mostly work that three.js would be doing for you instead if you were using regular objects (not quite, three.js would be updating the modelViewMatrix and so on for each frame and every object while my example updates computed position and orientation). For the question about drawcalls see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853856/why-are-draw-calls-expensive – so drawcalls get slow because the gpu doesn't get data fast enough, which isn't the case here.

Comment: @MartinSchuhfuß I'd like to try this, it would definitely have only one draw. A few questions: 1) This doesn't require a ShaderMaterial (shaders), right? Just vanilla Three? 2) But would Three assume it has to transform all the vertices? Your use of Three matrix operations seems to suggest not. BTW: Tnx for the great tweet on Gravity!

Comment: 1) no, it would work with any of the three.js materials (you might need to add additional attributes for normals and uv-coordinates depending on the material). 2) three.js is only concerned with the mesh as a whole, not with the vertices within the mesh. The vertices are sent to the GPU "as is". Oh and thank you for the inspiration for the gravity-codepen :)