# Setting bounds on particle movement

Tags: javascript, three.js, particles

I am creating particles and positioning them randomly with three.js:

```
for( var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++ ){
  var pX = Math.random() * 100-50;
  var pY =Math.random() * 100-50;
  var pZ = Math.random() * 100-50;
  particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX,pY,pZ);
  particle.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(Math.random(), Math.random(), pZ);
  particles.vertices.push(particle);
}
```

Then on my requestAnimationFrame update function I am moving the particles:

```
for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
    var particle = particles.vertices[i];
    particle.y += particle.velocity.y*speed;
    particle.x += particle.velocity.x*speed;
  }
```

How can I introduce some limits to the movement ? i.e when the particle reaches the edge of the screen I want to "bounce" them back.

Comment: I would probably store a `direction` vector and `velocity` value for each particle. For each frame, update the particle's position by its direction and velocity. If the particle hits or crosses a bounding edge, recalculate the direction and velocity so this or the next update will send it in the new direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to have direction and velocity for each particle. Direction is always a normalized `THREE.Vector3()`.

Then the code for your particles will be like this:

```
var particles = [];
var particleCount = 100;
var sizeX = 300;
var sizeY = 200;
var sizeZ = 100;

for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
  var pX = Math.random() * sizeX - sizeX / 2;
  var pY = Math.random() * sizeY - sizeY / 2;
  var pZ = Math.random() * sizeZ - sizeZ / 2;
  particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);
  particle.direction = new THREE.Vector3(Math.random() - .5, Math.random() - .5, 0).normalize(); // a normalized vector with random values for x,y
  particle.velocity = Math.random() * 50; // speed is 50 units per second
  particles.push(particle);
}
```

Supposing, you use `THREE.Points()`:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices = particles;

var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 5,
  color: "red"
}));
scene.add(points);
```

To set the proper speed (our 50 units per second) we'll need `THREE.Clock()` and its `.getDelta()` method:

```
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var shift = new THREE.Vector3(); //we will re-use it in the animation loop
var delta = 0; // we will re-use it in the animation loop
```

And in the animation loop we will do this:

```
  delta = clock.getDelta(); // get period between frames (in seconds)

  particles.forEach(function(p) {

    if (p.x > sizeX / 2 || p.x < -sizeX / 2) { // it's also can be like if (Math.abs(p.x > sizeX / 2))
      p.direction.x = -p.direction.x;
    }
    if (p.y > sizeY / 2 || p.y < -sizeY / 2) {
      p.direction.y = -p.direction.y;
    }
    if (p.z > sizeZ / 2 || p.z < -sizeZ / 2) {
      p.direction.z = -p.direction.z;
    }

    p.add(shift.copy(p.direction).multiplyScalar(p.velocity * delta)); // here we re-use the `shift` vector 
  })

  points.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true; // important, if you won't set it to true you won't get your particles moving
```

So that's it.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/tckek4co/) example

PS If you want to use `BufferGeometry`, then you can refer to this very good [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41906410/4045502)